# Matplotlib automatically sets insane datetime x axis range

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, bounds, scatter

Here's a trivial example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
plt.scatter(pd.to_datetime(['10:00', '11:00', '12:00']), [30, 40, 50])
plt.show()
```

It produces this chart, which is technically correct but has ridiculous x axis bounds:

[image: Chart with three dots in a vertical line]

What it should do:

[image: Chart with three dots along a diagonal line]

What's the easiest way (or ways) to fix this, and why is it so broken by default?

Comment: Interestingly, `plt.plot` scales the axis correctly for me

Comment: Well, this isn't exactly a dupe of that other question, but close enough...the relevant bug is https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9979

Answer (score 1):

You can set the limits of the axis:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

plt.scatter(pd.to_datetime(['10:00', '11:00', '12:00']), [30, 40, 50])
plt.axis(['9:00','13:00', None, None]) # or plt.xlim('9:00','13:00')
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
plt.show()
```

[image]